# Can you double press charges on a person?

Tags: criminal-law

Okay, let's just use Person A and B for the question.

Person A gets harassed by Person B. Then Person B takes all Person A's belongings and money, and he dumps it. Then Person A goes crazy red angry, then starts attacking Person B by punching, kicking, hair pulling, and then making Person B fall. Person B responds, but repeating it *harder,* until the point that it makes Person A call the police. Person A was so mad he wants to press charges for assault, 2 times. So, can you press charges two  times (double press charges)?

Comment: Not great writing, but I think it's actually a distinct question -- not whether both A and B can press charges, but whether A can press two separate charges of assault: for the assault leading up to the fall, and also for the assault after the fall.

Comment: @bdb484 I don't see any reference to person b assaulting person a

Answer (score 1):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

See [*Criminal Code*](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/c-46/FullText.html), s. 581(1):

> Each count in an indictment shall in general apply to a single transaction and shall contain in substance a statement that the accused or defendant committed an offence therein specified.

If there were two assaults, not as part of a continuing transaction, these should be indicted as two separate counts.